# Can't set body.innerHTML of new "about:blank"-window in Firefox (window.open())

Tags: javascript, firefox

*This is a Q&A-style-Thread because I couldn't find someone with this problem/with a solution.*

**Case:**

You have a javascript where you open a new window with window.open('*about:blank*', ...) and you want to set its content by setting `myWindowReference.document.body.innerHTML = SOMETHING`.

**Problem:**

Works fine in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera but **not in several (perhaps all?) versions of Firefox**. The page remains white but the log-message of `console.dir(myWindowReference.document.body.innerHTML);` is correct.

**Example Code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        window.onload = () => {
            let wind = window.open('about:blank', 'someName', 'resizable,scrollbars');
            wind.document.body.innerHTML = "HALLO, das ist ein TEST";
            wind.document.title = "TEST";
            wind.focus();
            console.log("wind.document.body.innerHTML:");
            // OUTPUT IS CORRECT
           // but page is blank
            console.dir(wind.document.body.innerHTML);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 2 (Better Solution)**:

Found out that there is no need to use "about:blank" in window.open() for an empty page. Because "about:blank" is a special page in Firefox this might be the reason for the bug. Just leave it empty and it works.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        window.onload = () => {
            let wind = window.open('', 'someName', 'resizable,scrollbars');
            wind.document.body.innerHTML = "HALLO, das ist ein TEST";
            wind.document.title = "TEST";
            wind.focus();
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some browsers will not allow the opener to access the new window/tab so *wind.document* is null.

Comment: Good to know but that's an issue that we didn't ran into in our project so far. The main browsers work now all as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

My guess is that Firefox isn't waiting internally until the window reference is fully there and therefore doesn't update the GUI but updates it somehow internally so that `console.dir(wind.document.body.innerHTML);` has the correct output anyway. I found out that a solution is using a timeout so that Firefox has enough time to fully build the window reference internally.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        window.onload = () => {
            let wind = window.open('about:blank', 'someName', 'resizable,scrollbars');
            // [B] DOES WORK
            window.setTimeout(() => {
                wind.document.body.innerHTML = "HALLO, das ist ein TEST";
                wind.document.title = "TEST";
            }, 1)  // USING A TIMEOUT IS THE SOLUTION

            /* [A] DOESN't WORK
            wind.document.body.innerHTML = "HALLO, das ist ein TEST";
            wind.document.title = "TEST";
            */

            wind.focus();
            console.log("wind.document.body.innerHTML:");
            console.dir(wind.document.body.innerHTML);
            /*
            This log message is in either way ([A] and [B]) correct in Firefox.
            With [A] there is no content and no title set to the window, althrough it is visible.
            With [B] it works. Seems like Firefox is internally not waiting for the right reference/
            until the window is opened.
            */
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```